# Reducing the amout of entries when creating a TEMPORARY TABLE in SQLite3

Tags: sqlite, left-join, union, temp-tables, create-table

I've got 2 databases with 3 tables in a single SQLite3 database connection. I create a temporary table on these tables/databases to support better and quicker searching/filtering.
Here is an example. The real tables are much bigger.
1st table:
rowid(unique)|firstname|lastname
2nd table:
id(from 1st table)|phonenumber
3rd table:
id(from 1st table)|emailaddress
I've got 2 (even more in the future) databases of this kind. To create a temporary table I do the following: (There is one database connection and a separate database "pb" attached.)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table AS 
   SELECT * FROM pb.name_table 
      LEFT JOIN pb.phone_table ON (pb.name_table.id=pb.phone_table.id) 
      LEFT JOIN pb.email_table ON (pb.name_table.id=pb.email_table.id) 
   UNION SELECT * FROM name_table 
      LEFT JOIN phone_table ON (name_table.id=phone_table.id) 
      LEFT JOIN email_table ON (name_table.id=email_table.id);
```

This generates a flat table like this:
firstname|lastname|phonenumber|emailaddress

But (and this is finally the question) if a contact has (e.g.:) 3 phone numbers and 3 email addresses, I get 3*3 entries in the result table. The result table contains a combination of all phone number - email address combinations.
Is there a way to create a flat table with 3 entries only?

Current situation:
firstname - lastname - email1 - phone1
firstname - lastname - email1 - phone2
firstname - lastname - email1 - phone3
firstname - lastname - email2 - phone1
firstname - lastname - email2 - phone2
firstname - lastname - email2 - phone3
firstname - lastname - email3 - phone1
firstname - lastname - email3 - phone2
firstname - lastname - email3 - phone3

Optimal solution (maybe in a different order):
firstname - lastname - email1 - phone1
firstname - lastname - email2 - phone2
firstname - lastname - email3 - phone3

Comment: This would be rather complex. Why don't you ask how to improve the original search algorithm?

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but the main problem I have is that the client software requests a list of contacts with different filter and sort algorithms over at least 2 databases with 3 tables each. I have to generate a list of IDs first which matches the filter and sort criteria to not flood the whole memory we have. Then, the client software requests only "windows" of detailed contact information. If I use a temporary table, I have a unique ID in the table otherwise I have all IDs twice.

Comment: Creating a flattened table is a bad way of solving your *actual* problem. See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: Okay, maybe I've just shiftet the problem somewhere else. But how can I search in 2 databases in 2 different tables (each)? Something like this is not working:

Comment: SELECT * FROM (SELECT name_table.rowid, name_table.origin, email_table.email_emailaddress FROM name_table, email_table LEFT JOIN email_table ON (name_table.id=email_table.id) WHERE ( name_familyname LIKE 'Zimmermann' ) AND ( email_emailaddress LIKE '%Zim%' )

Comment: UNION SELECT pb.name_table.rowid, pb.name_table.origin, pb.email_table.email_emailaddress FROM pb.name_table LEFT JOIN pb.email_table ON (pb.name_table.id=pb.email_table.id) WHERE ( name_familyname LIKE 'Zimmermann' ) AND ( pb.email_table.email_emailaddress LIKE '%Zim%' )) ORDER BY CASE WHEN name_familyname IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, name_firstname DESC, name_familyname COLLATE BINARY;

Comment: Sorry, I had to split the SELECT.

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it took some time, but I got rid of the temporary table. I programmed a "QueryBuilder" which generates queries for given result/filter/sort/...

It's quiet complex, but - well - you have to do this for performance. :-)

Thanks!